# What happened to the Itachi Uchiha movie?

Tags: naruto

As far as I know, a movie based on [Itachi Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Uchiha) was about to come in March.
Can anyone please tell whether it's coming this year or is it delayed?

Here is a Reddit [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/3xfwjg/itachi_movie/) of the poster, and here is a YouTube video of the trailer:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wl89gnvXcTg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Itachi Shinden* adaptation has already started airing via Naruto Shippuden episode 451 and onwards.

[Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2016/02/05/video-naruto-shippuuden-itachi-shinden-hen-hikari-to-yami-anime-previewed)  notes that it began airing on March 3rd. Episode 451 aired on March 3rd and these episodes exactly follow the novels.

It is set to be aired until May.

Comment: I haven't gotten a chance to watch these episodes. Are you sure this side story is the promised adaptation of the Itachi Shinden novels?

Comment: http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2016/02/05/video-naruto-shippuuden-itachi-shinden-hen-hikari-to-yami-anime-previewed episode 451 aired on march 3 and these episodes exactly follow the novels

Comment: You should edit that information into your answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a movie. The *Itachi Shinden* novels are being adapted to a TV release, which will air this spring. I didn't see information about it beginning in March.

The Naruto [twitter account](https://twitter.com/naruto_movie/status/678105786866753536) shared a link to [TV Tokyo Naruto website](http://www.tv-tokyo.co.jp/anime/naruto/sp/story/) which has a small trailer and information about the release, which seems to indicate that it will begin airing in Japan on April 7th.