# Is Itachi Shinden a separate anime series or part of Naruto Shippuden itself?

Tags: naruto

I have followed Naruto only via its manga and, barring a few episodes, I haven't seen much of the animated series. Considering that the manga ended almost a year ago, I am very much out of the Naruto universe.

Few months ago, I came across some posts that mentioned Itachi getting a separate anime series of his own, with trailers of the series uploaded on YouTube. Today I saw some amvs  titled Itachi Shinden and a part of the episode which has Shisui and kid Itachi fighting the ANBU.

A few internet searches yielded that Itachi Shinden is actually an animated adaption of the novel of the same name. However, I couldn't find whether it's a separate series that was being talked about or part of Naruto Shippuden fillers.

Comment: A related question: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/30579/3578

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Itachi Shinden is in fact a part of the Naruto series. The myth is that Itachi Shinden will have its own anime, this is not true. Itachi Shinden will be an arc attached to the current Naruto Anime. In the current anime of Naruto, Itachi's life has been shown while he was active in the ANBU, however, the new arc introduces a new look to Itachi's life, his personal life. Not much is yet known but it's definitely an arc of Naruto seeing as it was also created by Masashi Kishimoto.

Anyway, I hope this helped you find your answer.