# Is there anything else that covers Itachi's story outside of the core anime and manga?

Tags: naruto

I liked Itachi's character a lot and wanted to know more about him.

Are there any movies, or perhaps some light novels that cover more of his story?

Comment: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Shinden_Book:_Light_and_Darkness This was a Light Novel, but believe it was adapted in the anime version as well!

Comment: I believe your are talking about Itachi Shinden?That has been converted to an arc in Naruto Shippuden.

Answer (score 1):

The core anime and manga cover much of Itachi's story, particularly if you're only looking for his "canon" story. However, he does appear in other media.

As Abhishek Mishra says, he appears in the OVA "Sunny Side Battle!" Here is a list of non-core anime/manga media Itachi appears in:

OVA:

- Hidden Leaf Village Grand Sports Festival! (as a cameo)
- Sunny Side Battle!

Game:

- Naruto Shippūden: Ultimate Ninja Storm Revolution--Ninja Escapades (OVAs within the game)

Novel:

- Naruto Jinraiden: The Day the Wolf Howled (more Sasuke's reflection on Itachi's actions)
- Itachi Shinden: Book of Bright Light/ Itachi Shinden: Book of Dark Night (related to Shippuden #451-458--[this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30579/what-happened-to-the-itachi-uchiha-movie/30833#30833) says it follows the novels, [Naruto Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Shinden_Book:_Light_and_Darkness) says it doesn't, I don't know enough to say either way)
- Akatsuki Hiden: Evil Flowers in Full Bloom

Movie:

- Road to Ninja: Naruto the Movie

Naruto Wikia has a list of [all video games in which he's a playable character](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Uchiha#Video_Games).

Answer (score 0):

The main storyline of Itachi is in the anime and manga.

However, if you want to see and know more about Itachi, you can see the NARUTO OVA "Sunny Side Battle!".

You can also watch him in certain cutscenes of Ultimate Ninja Storm 4 game, and other games.